# Primefaces saving datatable values

Tags: primefaces, datatable

Iam displaying datatable with some empty rows using primefaces datatable by associating datatable with an empty list class.

Iam able to display the desired number of rows.

Can anyone tell me how to store the datatable after entering all the rows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the values entered in the datatable are being binded to the backing bean . So iam iterating through a list and saving each row.